# If $x(y-z), y(z-x), z(x-y)$ form a geometric progression, then what equation does the common ratio satisfy?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

If the distinct nonzero numbers $x(y - z)$, $y(z - x)$, $z(x - y)$ form a geometric progression with common ratio $r$, then what equation does $r$ satisfy?

---

I set $r$ = $\frac{y(z-x)}{x(y-z)}$ = $\frac{z(x-y)}{y(z-x)}$ and then cross multiplied and tried to simplify the algebra but I couldn't get it to work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$y(z-x)=rx(y-z)\tag1$$
$$z(x-y)=ry(z-x)\tag2$$

From $(1)$,
$$z(y+rx)=xy(r+1)\tag3$$
From $(2)$,
$$z(x-y-ry)=-xyr\tag4$$

From $(3)(4)$, we have
$$(z(y+rx)(x-y-ry)=)\quad xy(r+1)(x-y-ry)=-xyr(y+rx)$$
Dividing the both sides by $xy$ gives
$$(r+1)(x-y-ry)=-r(y+rx),$$
i.e.
$$(r+1)(x-y)-r(r+1)y+ry+r^2x=0$$
i.e.
$$(r+1)(x-y)+r^2(x-y)=0$$
$$(r^2+r+1)(x-y)=0$$
Since $x-y\not=0$, we obtain
$$\color{red}{r^2+r+1=0}.$$